# How to make new versions of Stm32CubeIDE (1.9+) to debug fake stm32 chips

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

So, I have an old installation of Stm32CubeIDE 1.6.1. And, a new installation of Stm32CubeIDE 1.13.1. And, a bunch of blue pills with CH32 chips from the chip shortage times.

The 1.13.1 version does not want to upload firmware to fake stm32 chips, whilst the old one does.

The error it shows is "Could not verify ST device!":

[image]

Most anwsers on the internet suggest modyfing the target/stm32f1xx.cfg file in the OpenOCD plugin folder, to disable the chip id checking (fake chip id is 0x2ba01477, original should be 0x1ba01477, as confirmed by screenshot). But, my 1.6.1 installation has a very similar cfg file that **should** check for the ID, but in fact, it does not stop the firmware upgrade process at all:

```
#jtag scan chain
if { [info exists CPUTAPID] } {
   set _CPUTAPID $CPUTAPID
} else {
   if { [using_jtag] } {
      # See STM Document RM0008 Section 26.6.3
      set _CPUTAPID 0x3ba00477
   } {
      # this is the SW-DP tap id not the jtag tap id
      set _CPUTAPID 0x1ba01477
   }
}

swj_newdap $_CHIPNAME cpu -irlen 4 -ircapture 0x1 -irmask 0xf -expected-id $_CPUTAPID
```

So, the question is: **how to modify new Stm32CubeIDE installations to be able to program and debug fake chips again?** What has changed? Could it be not the config files, but a new version of the GDB server?

Please, please do not answer with suggestions of using only genuine chips. You know perfectly well it does not answer the question, and, according to the large amount of similar questions on the internet without any luck in fixing the problem, I am not the only one interested in such a solution.

Also, just using an old version of stm32cubeide is an option, sure, but not the perfect one. And, again, suggesting to stay with it does not answer the question - besides, it may update some of it's components (like the GDB server) and break everything.

Comment: What makes you think the only difference between the real and fake chip is a single bit in the id?

Comment: ".... large amount of similar questions on the internet without any luck in fixing the problem .... " indicates that you most probably will be without any luck here also. ST invested lot of money to development of their IDE and and thay naturaly can use its power to make clones less attractive on the market. If you use non-genuine chip, you will need to use non-genuine IDE also.

Comment: Theoreticaly someone can reverse enginner way the ST use to detect clone and crack it, but it cost lost of time (=money) and it is ususaly cheaper to buy genuine chip. Additionaly such crack will work unless ST release new version.

Comment: @Misaz basing the IDE on open-source solutions and stating so then seems kinda bad. Pretty sure there is a way. Will post any solution I will find here.

Comment: Have you considered using genuine chip for development and fakes in production for saving cost?

Comment: @Misaz that more than makes sense, but right now, when the chip shortage is over, the profit is not as much as it was before. It's just that I have a bunch of blue pills with fake ch32 chips. About the STM32CubeIDE situation - I've actually investigated a bit and it seems like fake chip detection was always in the GDB-Server and OpenOCD config, as well as in the stm32 gdb implemetation which OpenOCD connects to. It's just that the IDE itself did not stop the flashing process before.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to the problem. I have been recently struggling with it with my STM32F407 based board i bought from AliExpress.

Comment: @SheikhMuhammadJunaidAslam Nope. Using version 1.6.1 saves the day.